# select two numbers from the same column using a union but with two different order bys

Tags: mysql, union

So i need to select the city with highest and lowest population in the same query using a Union statement... I have tried almost every answer on the site, google, mysql.com and mysql tutorials... nothing works so
this is my code

```
(select name, population from city order by population asc limit 1)
union
( select name, population from city order by population desc limit 1)
```

it is not working obviously, I dont want the answer, I just need to understand why it isnt working and what to fix please and thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error? What you have ought to work just fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fce4/1

Comment: That looks OK to me - what error are you getting and do each of the queries work when you execute them on their own?

Comment: they work on their own. the message is
Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @BushTronicz What MySQL version are you using? Your SQL code is _exactly_ as you have it above? It really should work...

Comment: I the optimizer possibly combining the two queries? Pehaps changing UNION to UNION ALL would help, by eliminating the sort and duplicate elimination implied by a simple UNION. (I am a SQL Server guy so forgive me if I have MySQL syntax not quite right.)

Comment: using mysql workbench 5.2.44 CE

Comment: and it is exactly as it is above